# Error When Adding Self-Refrencing Foreign Key SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table called `User` that has columns like:

```
|UserID numeric(18,0)
|...
|SupervisorUserID numeric(18,0)
```

`UserID` is the primary key and I have other foreign key relationships working (table to table). But when I try to add a relation between `SupervisorUserID` and `UserID` I get the following error in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: SQL Server Management Studio error]

What could be the issue here?

Comment: What T-SQL is the GUI trying to run when you get that error?

Comment: What is the table definition of table `User`? Is `UserID` a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

The message looks quite straightforward. Check if your index is unique.

Comment: Please, put the query and both tables structures in your question

Answer (score 0):

When you create a foreign key relationship in the same table make sure you put the primary key field under "Primary key table" and the foreign key field under "Foreign key table".  Doing the reverse will give you the error described.